# Center Align ul shows left aligned in safari browse only

Tags: html, css

I have a simple menu, which is center aligned and show center aligned in FF, Chrome and IE but is left aligned in safari browser.

Not sure if i have to use any specific css property to center align it

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header-row2">
      <div id="cssmenu">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>

          <li><a href="/Page1.aspx">Page One</a></li>
          <li><a href="/Page2.aspx">Page Two</a></li>

        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NxmrBQ

Safari browser 5.1.7 on windows 7
[image]

Comment: I can see menu center in safari also

Comment: @ketan, i have version 5.1.7 and n this it show as left aligned. Which version do you have

Comment: Pretty strange, I have added screenshot of same

Comment: I think `justify-content: center;` not support in safari.

Comment: WORKING : Based on Koschtik, solution http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PZgpQq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Safari 5.1 doesn't support justify-content, i had a similar issue.
Try this:

```css
#cssmenu {
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-pack: center; /* justify-content */
  -webkit-box-align: center; /* align-items */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change `li { display:block;}`

to

```
ul { font-size: 0;text-align: center} li { display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;font-size: 16px;}
```

or use Flexbox

[flexbox-guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: I think it is issue with window mac version as support for this is stopped by apple. may be that is the reason... i tried webkit flex options also

Comment: I think testing in safari windows is not necessary. IF you really want support it your can play with properties ul{ display:table;text-align:center }  li{ display: table-cell,}

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#cssmenu ul{display:table; margin:0 auto;}
```